# Who approves suggested edits if no one has 500 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderation

Who approves suggested edits if no one has 500 reputation?

Do the edits just stack up until someone crosses the threshold, and then they have to go through reviewing all of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do, from time to time.

It shouldn't take too long for a couple people to get 500 rep. Until then, though, we'll approve what edits we can semi-regularly. I took a look at the queue just now, and it only had three edits.

- One was a content edit that materially modifies the facts in an answer. While probably good, I don't have the domain expertise here, and it'll have to wait until someone hits 500 rep or someone who can evaluate it drops by.
- One was a minor edit that changed only a few characters, which I skipped.
- One made a question's title clearer, which I approved.

Comment: I recommend approving minor edits that contain improvements.

Comment: Don't forget the post author can review the edits made to their own questions or answers. Although it may not always  be the case.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket To my subjective read, it was in the grey area where it could be seen as 'too minor'. But, community members should begin to make decisions about where that line is for the site soon enough, so I left it.